# Anaconda3をしっかりアンインストールするにはどうしたら良いですか？

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Anaconda3にkeras&Tensorflowをインストールしたところ、PyCharmの挙動がおかしくなりました。

Anaconda3をコントロールパネルからアンインストールし、その後にAnaconda3を再インストールしましたが、同問題が起こってしまいます。

Anaconda3をしっかりアンインストールするにはどうしたら良いですか？
確認すべき箇所や解決方法などご存知ありましたら、アドバイスなどいただきたく思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Windows7 64bit
Anaconda 2019.10
conda 4.7.12

Comment: 「最新版です」だと時間が経つとどのバージョンを指すか分からなくなってしまいますし、リリース最新版なのか開発版なのかが分かりません。また、Anaconda のバージョンと conda コマンドのバージョンが別にあるのも話をややこしくしそうです。`conda list anaconda$` で Anaconda のバージョンが、`conda --version` で conda コマンドのバージョンが表示できるので、こちらを参考にバージョン情報を質問文に追記してみてください :)

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。コメントいただいた方法でAnacondaバージョン追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda の公式ドキュメントがあります：[Uninstalling Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Windows の場合、次のふたつの方法が紹介されています。

### 1. 手動で関連ファイルを削除してからアンインストールする方法

- まず、エクスプローラから envs フォルダと pkgs フォルダを削除する。このフォルダの場所は設定によって異なるのですが、`conda info` コマンドを実行すると一覧が見れます。
- 次にコントロールパネルから Anaconda をアンインストールする。

### 2. Anaconda-Clean を使う方法

上の方法をまだ試していなければ使える方法です。こちらは細かい設定ファイルも含めて削除します。

- Anaconda-Clean をインストールする。

  ```sh
  conda install anaconda-clean
  ```
- そのまま `anaconda-clean` コマンドを実行して、ファイルを削除させる。Anaconda-Clean は、削除されるファイルのバックアップをホームディレクトリの `.anaconda_backup` に残したり、AnacondaProjects のファイルは残すことに注意してください。
- その後コントロールパネルから Anaconda をアンインストールする。